# How to display a single column in while loop using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, phpmyadmin

Please help me with this code below its not working as expected. I have a few records in a mysql table as below and using same column names mentioned below:

```
id    |    name        |    referrer
1     |    User1       |    referrer_one
2     |    User2       |    referrer_one
3     |    User3       |    referrer_one
4     |    User4       |    referrer_two
5     |    User5       |    referrer_two
```

I want the above data to be shown like below using PHP in a while loop:

```
Referrer Username      |     Total Referrals
referrer_one           |     3
referrer_two           |     2
```

I am using below code please tell me what am I doing wrong:

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Referrer Username</td>
    <td>Total Referrals</td>
  </tr>
  <?php
  $data = $db->query("SELECT referrer, count(*) as total_member FROM 
  user_registration GROUP BY referrer");          

  while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($data,MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
      foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
  ?>    
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo ($value['referrer']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo ($value['total_member']); ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } } ?>
</table>
```

After using the above code I'm getting below error message:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'referrer'
Warning: Illegal string offset 'total_member'
```

Please help me I really need the working solution!

Comment: Remove your foreach. You are currently looping over all you results, and then looping inside your results

Comment: Thank you for your answer it was quiet helpful.

Comment: No problem. I personnaly try as much as I can to draw / write what I have to do and how I expect to resolve my problems. It helps a lot to figure out what's wrong with the code and avoid doing thing automatically without really paying attention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the additional `foreach` loop, because 
[`mysqli_fetch_array()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) fetches a single record (result row) at a time.

Try this:

```
while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($data,MYSQLI_BOTH)) { ?>    
<tr>
  <td><?php echo ($res['referrer']); ?></td>
  <td><?php echo ($res['total_member']); ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

With the `while` loop you are already looping over every record in the result set, until there is no record left.

With the additional `foreach` loop you were looping over every single column of the returned record (4 in total, because you used `MYSQLI_BOTH`):

```
$key = 0 and $value = some scalar value ... 
$key = 'referrer' and $value = some scalar value ...
$key = 1 and $value = some scalar value ...
$key = 'total_member' and $value = some scalar value
```

Comment: Thank you Decent Dabbler, you made my day. Now its working as expected. Once again thank you for helping me, keep up the good work & God bless you :)

Comment: @SyedNaveed You are welcome, glad to hear it solved your problem. :)